# Impossible for me to understand a method of string search as described. What is uFFFF?

Tags: java, string, performance, algorithm, binary-search

I am reading something about searching for a (range of) string(s) in a sorted array of strings.

It says:

> If you want to find all strings starting with "h", you can run a
>   binary search for the strings "h" and "h\uFFFF". This gives all the
>   indexes of the band for all the keys that start with "h". Note that a
>   binary search can return the index where the string would be even if
>   it is not actually in the array.

I don't understand anything from this paragraph.

What is `h\uFFFF` how does it help/is used in the binary search and does the last sentense also mean that even this search is faulty?

Any help to understand what is being said here please?

Comment: `\uFFFF` is the max value for a unicode character, not used as a printable character

Comment: '\uFFFF' is an escape sequence for the code point U+FFFF, which is guaranteed by [the stanard](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFFF0.pdf) to not be a character. Is some special use for it being defined elsewhere in what you're reading?

Comment: @Sam Dehaan: *"\uFFFF is the max value for a unicode character"*...  Since Unicode 3.1 there are way more than 65 536 codepoint and a single Java *char* ain't enough to represent the new codepoints.  For example the Unicode character 'MUSICAL SYMBOL G CLEF' has the Unicode codepoint 0x0001D11E (quite more than 0xFFFF) and needs two Java *char* to be represented: "\uD8334\uDD1E".  This SNAFU comes from the fact that Java (and it's *char* primitive type) was defined before Unicode 3.1 came out.  In summary: no, \uFFFF is definitely **NOT** the max value for a Unicode codepoint.

Answer (score 9):

\uFFFF is the "character" that sorts last in the 16-bit "alphabet", i.e. after any valid letter, character, or special symbol.

When you do binary search for a string in a sorted array, you find a place where that string could be inserted. When you have multiple identical strings, you get a location ahead of the first one. When you append "the last letter of the alphabet" after your string, the insertion point will be after the last of the identical strings, hence giving you a range of identical strings in a sorted array.

Imagine this: suppose you are not allowed to use letter `Z` in your words. Now you have a sorted array of strings:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6
aab abb abc abc abd bcx bdy
```

If you search for `abc`, binary search tells you the first place where you can insert it, which is 2. If you search for `abcZ`, thoug, binary search would return 4, because `abcZ` comes alphabetically right after `abc`. This lets you know that the range between 2, inclusive, and 4, exclusive, is occupied by the string `abc`. If both searches return the same number, you know that the string is not present in the array.

In the paragraph that you quoted, `\uFFFF` plays the role of the "prohibited letter Z" from my example.

Comment: I think your example is not correct.You have `abc`{2} to be right child of root and also you have `abc`{3} to be left grandchild of `aab` {root}

Comment: In binary search left child is `2*i+1` and right child `2*i+2`.This is what I mean.I corrected my comment

Comment: @user384706 I think you are misunderstanding my example: there is no root there - indeed, there's no hierarchy of any kind. It's just a plain array of strings, sorted alphabetically in ascending order.

Comment: @user384706 I think you are talking about a [binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), not a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Binary search divides an array in half, checks the value, and decides whether to continue the search to the left or to the right of the current midpoint, continuing when it finds the result, or when it knows that the value is not there.

Comment: You are right.But why does the search return `2` if `abc` is already in the array?Shouldn't it return 3?It searches for `abc` and it goes to the middle i.e. `3` and it is there

Comment: @user384706 Some standard implementations of binary search make a guarantee to return the first element in the range of equal values (for example, STL's `lower_bound` does; Java and .NET implementations do not make such guarantee). The paragraph that you quoted silently assumes that the array does not contain multiple copies of the `"h"` string, or that the binary search returns the first location of an equal range.

Answer (score 3):

`\uFFFF` is the largest possible character in Java. Since the strings are sorted, searching for `h` will find the start of the range while `h\uFFFF` will find the end (assuming unicode strings here) since no second character can be larger than `\uFFFF`. Even if it can't match the string exactly, the search will return the index of where the target *would be* even if it's not really there.

*update: `\uFFFF` is the largest possible sortable unicode character in 16 bit block, if you are working with 32 bit blocks use `U+10FFFF` (whatever that is in Java). I've personally never worked 32 bit unicode blocks in Java. See the section 16.7 of [the 5.2.0 spec](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.2.0/ch16.pdf).*

> U+FFFF and U+10FFFF. These two noncharacter code points have the
>   attribute of being associated with the largest code unit values for
>   particular Unicode encoding forms. **In UTF-16, U+FFFF is associated
>   with the largest 16-bit code unit value, FFFF** . U+10FFFF is
>   associated with the largest legal UTF-32 32-bit code unit value,
>   10FFFF . This attribute renders these two noncharacter code points
>   useful for internal purposes as sentinels. **For example, they might be
>   used to indicate the end of a list, to represent a value in an index
>   guaranteed to be higher than any valid character value, and so on**

Comment: So this symbol `\uFFFF` helps you pass a character in hex in a `String`?

Comment: that is language dependent but it "means" the the unicaode character that is known as "FFFF". SOftof like ASCII 0xFF...

Comment: Look at my last sentence to under stand the last sentence of the excerpt.

Comment: The last sentence is explained by @Andrew's last sentence. The search will find the spot in the array where the string *would* be. If it is in the array, this is the index of the string. If it isn't, this is the index it would be in if it was added.

Comment: @AndrewWhite: once again ; )   *"\uFFFF" is the largest possible unicode character"*...  Not at all.  This is totally wrong.  The latest version of Unicode defines approximately 109 000 characters.  And, despite popular belief, a Java *char* is definitely **NOT** enough to represent a Unicode character.  There are 65 536 codepoints in the *Basic Multilingual Plane* but since Unicode 3.1 additional planes have been added.   In Java you need two *char* to encode characters outside the BMP, like this one: *"\uD834\uDD1E" (Unicode codepoint 0x0001D11E, way above 0xFFFF).

Comment: @user988052: for the context of this question it was sufficient as that was the intent of the original passage.

Comment: @AndrewWhite: *"for the context of this question it was sufficient"*...  I think the original paragraph quoted is extermely wrong and misleading but, still, it doesn't change the fact: *"\uFFFF is the largest possible unicode character"* is still wrong : )

Comment: @user988052: see my update and comment; I would be interested in you providing a sortably larger unicode character where the first char in byte order is smaller than \uFFFF

Comment: @user988052: to quote you "`\uD834\uDD1E` (Unicode codepoint 0x0001D11E, way above 0xFFFF)" is totally wrong (pun here) from the context of this question which deals with sorted order in java which takes units in 16 bit chunks. please be careful when using "total wrong" when referring to people's answers.

Comment: @Andrew White: you keep ignoring the point and, instead of admitting your error and editing your question, you try to change what I said.  But the **facts** stays (that's the fun thing with facts, you can't argue with them ;)   You wrote: *"\uFFFF is the largest possible unicode character"*, which is blatantly false.  So, basically Andrew, you're telling anyone here that 0x1D11E is smaller than 0xFFFF?  So, to make things clear for everyone, you stand by your two assertions: *"uFFFF is the largest possible Unicode character"* and *"0x1DD11E is not above 0xFFFF"*?

Comment: @Andrew White: *"I would be interested in you providing a sortably larger unicode character where the first char in byte order is smaller than \uFFFF"*.  You keep dodging my point.  And your question still contains the following wrong statement *"\uFFFF is the largest possible Unicode character"*.  This is blatantly wrong and it's not open for discussion.  No matter how much you try to shift the discussion.  You didn't write: *"uFFFF is the largest possible Java char"*.  You wrote *"uFFFF is the largest possible Unicode character"*.  Don't try to distort the facts that I'm stating.

Comment: @user988052: I removed the word "unicode" but I am trying to answers questions in the same context and as simply as possible. The stated algorithm is not wrong or misleading as you stated in your answer and as you imply in mine; I even updated my answer to clarify sortably larger later.

Comment: Java represents Unicode characters as fixed-size 16-bit words.  The value 0xFFFF may not be a permissible Unicode character, but it is the largest possible value for a Java string element, which is what your actual question is about.  Do you really fail to understand the (correct) answer, or are you engaging in gratuitous pedantic nit-picking?

Answer (score 2):

The `\uFFFF` sequence in Java denotes the character with Unicode codepoint U+FFFF. However, the codepoint does not encode a character at all:

> U+FFFF is used to represent a numeric value that is guaranteed not to be a character, for uses such as the final value at the end of an index.

See these references: [Unicode Technical Report #16](http://unicode.org/reports/tr16/#Scalar%20Values), [this Unicode character chart](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFFF0.pdf) and [this character definition](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ffff/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have specified, searching for `h` will find the beginning of the range of strings starting with `h`, while `h\uFFFF` will find the end (exclusive) of the range of strings starting with `h` in your set of data.

The last sentence means that searching for `h\uFFFF` will show you where you would insert such a string, if it does not exist in your data, which is why it gives you the exclusive end of your range.